# How to specify an URL after the submission of a form?

Tags: html, forms, url, redirect

***This is hypothetical but I wonder if this is possible.***

Let's say I have a single input form on a page of my website that collects emails.

```
<form>
  <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Once the button is clicked, I use a third-party service (say Zapier) to get a unique & public URL that is external to my website (say a link to a newly created Trello board).

**Pseudocode**

```
When someone submit his email in my form
  Zapier is triggered and creates a new public Trello board
  Zapier posts back the URL of the Trello board
  The person is redirected to the Trello board
```

Is there a way to perform this?

I'm not familiar with redirections yet. Maybe there's a way to redirect temporarily (302?) until the Trello URL posted by Zapier is catched, leading to the right redirection.

If it's not feasible, how would you handle this?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Process the email address on the server side: Trigger the Zapier board creation and get the URL back from them. Then redirect the user to his new Trello board. For example, in PHP you execute `header('Location: ' . $trelloBoardURL);`.